# Prove that $GL_2(R)$ is open in$ M_2(R)$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, proof-verification

Prove that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is open in$ M_2(\mathbb{R})$

My solution : Define the map $\phi:M_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by sending $A$ to $\det(A)$ .

I guess $\phi$ is continuous . As $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is open  $GL_2(\mathbb{R}) =\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})$ is open also open .

I would like to verify if my solution is correct .

Comment: Yes, it is correct, though you need to explain why $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: Correct indeed, but "guessing" can be a tad weak an argument...remark that it is a polynomial in $\;n\;$ variables and that is.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to note that if $\|A\| <1$ (and $\|\cdot\|$ is a submultiplicative norm), then
$(I+A)^{-1} = I+A+A^2+\cdots$. In particular, if $\|A\|<1$, then $I+A$
is invertible.

Hence if $B$ is invertible, and
$\|H\| < {1 \over \|B^{-1}\|}$, then we have $\|B^{-1}H \| <1$ and so $ (I + B^{-1}H)^{-1} B^{-1}= (B(I + B^{-1}H))^{-1} = (B+H)^{-1}  $ from
which we see that $B+H$ is invertible.